# How to print a long string using std::fprintf()?

Tags: c++

I have a string of size 1024 and I would like to print it using std::fprintf().
I tried the following:

```
FILE* m_file = .....;
char * msg = .....; // (size of 1024)
std::fprintf(m_file, "'%.1024s'\n", msg);
```

But in the output file, I see the msg printed only up to the length of 1000.

Could not find anything in documentation about it, does anyone have a clue?

**Update:**

It turns out that somewhere during our pipeline, the string is being cut at size 1000, and that's I did not see the whole string after fprintf

Comment: Use std::fstream.

Comment: Code exceeded minimal _Environmental limit_ of 254.  You are on your own.  What is `BUFSIZ` on you system?

Comment: @manni66 I could use it, but this is a legacy code and I don't want to change too much. Also I'm curious why this is happening

Comment: Post the content of `m_file[]` or how it was populated.

Comment: How did you determine that the size of the string is 1024? Did you double check with `strlen`?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz yup, I checked it during a debug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"I see the msg printed only up to the length of 1000." --> `"%.1024s"` prints up to the the length of the string or 1024, whichever is smaller.

Apparently `m_file[1000]` is `'\0'`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an [`ofstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream) instead. Presuming that you have initialized your `ofstream m_file` successfully you can do:

```
m_file.write(msg, 1024)
```